# .Net-Core ReportGenerator - How To Recursively Match Cobertura Coverage Files

Tags: .net-core, reportgenerator

I am a .net-core core user trying to figure out how to generate a HTML test coverage report using [reportgenerator](https://libraries.io/github/danielpalme/ReportGenerator).

I have managed to collect code cobertura coverage statistics. These exist within test assemblies projects under *Tests/*:

```sh
dotnet test --collect:"XPlat Code Coverage"
```

I am trying to use [reportgenerator](https://libraries.io/github/danielpalme/ReportGenerator) to produce a HTML coverage report from these files.

I have tried the following commands, none of which find any matching coverage statistics:

```sh
dotnet reportgenerator -reports:./Tests/**/coverage.cobertura.xml
dotnet reportgenerator -reports:Tests/**/coverage.cobertura.xml
dotnet reportgenerator -reports:./Tests/UnitTests/**/coverage.cobertura.xml
dotnet reportgenerator -reports:Tests/UnitTests/**/coverage.cobertura.xml
```

All of the above commands generate the following output:

```
zsh: no matches found: -reports:Tests/**/coverage.cobertura.xml
```

I have verified that the path is correct, e.g. `ls Tests` and `ls Tests/UnitTests`

Has anyone managed to generate a HTML coverage report with reportgenerator, using globbing so that the test coverage statistic files will be recursively matched and merged?

**Update**
@Daniel It works!

I think the targetDir must be a mandatory option so the full working command is:

```
dotnet reportgenerator "-reports:Tests/UnitTests/**/*.xml" "-targetDir:coveragereports"
```

Comment: All paths should work. ReportGenerator supports globbing. Make sure to use the correct working directory. If it does not work, try with a fixed path to a single file, then add globbing.

Comment: Can you share the output of ReportGenerator?

Comment: Thanks for responding, appreciated :) Added requested details to question

Comment: I created a sample on Github: https://github.com/danielpalme/coveragesample/tree/wildcardtest Globbing finds all files. See https://github.com/danielpalme/coveragesample/blob/wildcardtest/.github/workflows/ci.yml for my configuration

Comment: @Daniel Thanks! Much appreciated :) Will use this a basis to try and figure out what is happening in my local repository....

Comment: @Daniel It works! If I do this....```dotnet reportgenerator "-reports:Tests/UnitTests/**/*.xml"``` surrounding the -reports option containing the relative path in double quotes. I think the targetDir must be a mandatory option so the full working command is: ```dotnet reportgenerator "-reports:Tests/UnitTests/**/*.xml" "-targetDir:coveragereports"``` I will update question with these details....